# Javascript : separating array defined value that's undefined and array value that's not defined

Tags: javascript, undefined

How do I now check if the value is defined as undefined, or if it's really not defined?
eg.

```
var a = [];
a[0] = undefined;

// a defined value that's undefined
typeof a[0] === "undefined";

// and a value that hasn't been defined at all
typeof a[1] === "undefined";
```

Is there a way to separate these two? it's possible touse a for-in loop to go through the array, but is there a lighter way?

Comment: Undefined means it's undefined--if you explicitly set something to undefined, that's also undefined, by definition. You could use null, check the index against the array length, etc.

Comment: True. I simplified my real problem for the question to make more sense. The array is really a collection from data, where undefined is a valid value that tells me something is not defined. The problems seem to come when the array is [undefined], and that made me wonder about the question topic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator to check if a given index is present in the array, regardless of its actual value

```
var t = [];
t[0] = undefined;
t[5] = "bar";

console.log( 0 in t ); // true
console.log( 5 in t ); // true
console.log( 1 in t ); // false
console.log( 6 in t ); // false

if( 0 in t && t[0] === undefined ) {
     // the value is defined as "undefined"
}

if( !(1 in t) ) {
    // the value is not defined at all
}
```

Comment: same answer as mine but with a bit much explanation :)

Comment: I didn't see it, we've posted at the same time :)

Answer (score 3):

you can check if index is in given array:

```
0 in a // => true
1 in a // => false
```